# How do I install Android Studio into IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Now that Android Studio is out is it possible to install it into IntelliJ Ultimate?

I opened the Preferences > Plugins screen. This is what I see:

[image]

I don't remember installing Android Support at all. Also, all the plugins were selected when I opened the preferences panel. Does this mean these are all installed? I'm confused by what I see.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Android Studio is just an IDE with a custom compilation of IntelliJ plugins. You can install / activate any IntelliJ plugin in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (but not the other way around). If you want "Android Studio", just activate the Android Support plugin (File -> Settings -> Plugins).

Comment: Is Android support the same as Android Studio? For Eclipse it appears it is not, http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html. "If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates."

Comment: IMHO yes. See also: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/

"Is Android Studio a fork of IntelliJ IDEA?
No. Android Studio and the Android plugin for IntelliJ IDEA are built from the same code, and all of the changes in Android Studio are, and will continue to be, available in IntelliJ IDEA releases."

Comment: @gigawatts: Have you had time to try what I suggested?

Comment: I went into Preferences > Plugins and I'm confused by what I see. It looks like Android Support is already installed? I've updated my original post with a screen shot.

Comment: If you have not deactivated the plugin at first startup of IntelliJ, it is already activated. So in your case you do not have to do anything - you are ready for android development ;)

Answer (score 17):

Android support is bundled with IntelliJ IDEA (either Community Edition or Ultimate). All bundled plugins are activated by default. There isn't anything you can (or need to) install separately.

Now, because Android Studio is limited to Android projects built with Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA is more generic, there are certain differences in functionality between the two (Android Studio always builds projects with Gradle, while IntelliJ IDEA has its own build system capable of importing Gradle build files; the new project wizard in Android Studio is different). There is no possibility to modify IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to match Android Studio in those aspects.

Comment: Thanks for noting this difference.

Comment: I wonder if 5 years later this is still true... Android Studio Gradle is pretty complex now, with library projects, api / compile dependencies, Bundles ... Is IntelliJ Ultimate able to compile a big Android project?

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ IDEA now delegates building of projects to Gradle by default, so it allows to compile all Android projects. IntelliJ IDEA's own build system does not support any new Android features, but by default it's not used for projects imported from Gradle.