# How do I install android SDK alongside Intellij to match what is done in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have seen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736433/how-do-i-install-android-studio-into-intellij) that Intellij Idea (Ultimate) comes configured with all Android Studio plugins.

But I reckon Android Studio also comes with a preconfigured Android SDK.

I believe Intellij doesn't come with Android SDK does it ? So should I install Android SDK normally or are there special things to do to make it work nicely with Intellij ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and extract the SDK manually.

Make sure you enable android support:
File->Settings->Plugins->Android Support

For better workflow I recommend adding the android specific actions to the menu bar:

File->Settings->Appearance & Behaviour -> Menus and Toolbars

More information can be found here:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Android+Development